# Using EntLib logging app block to send email using auth/secure smtp server

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

The entlib logging application block doesn't allow for setting username/password or useSSL in the EmailTraceListenerData config type, is there a common solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to do a [custom trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139989.aspx) for that.  Here's a [slightly older example](http://authemailtracelisten.codeplex.com/) of exactly what you're trying to do.  But, the logging block has been around for ages, so that example might just work.   You can vote for EntLib5 features [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2009/03/27/enterprise-library-5-0-tentative-product-backlog-published-story-feature-prioritization-is-open-your-participation-is-invited.aspx). :)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up extending the EmailTraceListenerData class (and the others that went with them) to add the required config properties and functionality

Answer (score 1):

Authentication has been added to EmailTraceListener in [Enterprise Library 5.0](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5)

Also, if you must stay on 4.1, see the workarounds [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/57165?ProjectName=entlib).

Comment: awesome, can't wait to upgrade